# ASP.NET MVC5 Identity: Avoid changing logged-in user after registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to change the default Register Action of MVC5 ASP.NET Application.My Scenario is such that authorized users (such as admin) will login and they can create new users. However using below snippet, after creating user, current logged-in user will change to registered user.

How can I change below code to avoid changing logged-in user?

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName,Name=model.Name };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: registered user is logged in because after "SignInAsync" is called, its main work is login the user.. Remove that line of "SignInAsync".

Comment: You will want a separate admin only action that is not `[AllowAnonymous]` and checks the person is admin; also pass in two usernames (admin, new user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove SignInAsync and add [Authorize] annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName,Name=model.Name };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    if (!User.IsAuthenticated)  // if they're already logged in, don't log in again
        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```